# jQuery Cross Domain Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, cross-domain

We are doing a jQuery post out to a jsp file.

We are including the full url to the jsp file that will return a string but in IE and FF the request is being blocked.

Is there a way around this?

```
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type : "post",
                    url  : "http://www.mydomain.com/my.jsp",
                    data : {string:"some string"},
                    success:doSuccess
                }
```

Changing the post to a get net's us the same data but would it also cause an XSS issue?

**does using $.get have XSS issues?**

Answer (score 2):

You can reformat your output as JSONP. Full description here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Just for reference, the reason that your browsers are blocking this is to prevent cross domain scripting attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting . JSONP adds 'padding' to your string and prevents the string becoming a threat.

Comment: yeah sure i get that.  we are at a client and our site is hosted on a server on their premises.  so our application is calling a page within the same domain.  however, our main page is rendered within their cms so potentially coming from the other domain

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue (The CMS was SharePoint, but same principle). JSONP was the most elegant way to get around this. You just have to work out to to format your string as JSONP in Java (maybe http://code.google.com/p/jsonp-java/ )

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a cross domain ajax request? What is the domain of the page which request the ajax resource?

Due to security reasons, support for cross domain ajax requests are limited.

This may give [some input](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) to you.

Comment: I should mention we're not using php.