# jQuery XSS Issue

Tags: java, jquery, xss

I have this question;

[jQuery Cross Domain Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211697/jquery-cross-domain-errors)

I was wondering whether changing the "post" to a "get" would solve the XSS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would'nt change anything that belongs to XSS. It doesn't matter how you send the data, the point is how you work with the data(do you validate them proper before working with them). I still did'nt see if the problem there is [XSS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Scripting) or [sameOriginPolicy](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) , what definitly are different things.